# Proofs that NM-CPA implies IND-Cpa and $\text{IND-CCA} \leftrightarrow \text{NM-CCA}$

Tags: provable-security, chosen-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack, semantic-security, malleability

I am looking for a proof for the following two claims from "Serious Cryptography" by Aumasson.

> NM-CPA implies IND-CPA. [...] IND-CCA and NM-CCA are equivalent notions that imply the presence of the other.

where IND-CPA/IND-CCA and NM-CPA/CCA are defined as indistinguishability and non-malleability under chosen plaintext/chiphertext respectively.

Where can I find those proofs?

Answer (score 1):

This paper, AFAICT: [https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/relations.pdf](https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/relations.pdf)

It is about the security of public-key encryption, but the proofs about the relations between security definitions are applicable to symmetric encryption.